# Multiple bash scripts can't run asynchronously within spawned child processes

Tags: node.js, bash, asynchronous, child-process

This was running good for single call asynchronously:

```
"use strict";

function bashRun(commandList,stdoutCallback,completedCallback)
{
     const proc=require("child_process");
     const p=proc.spawn("bash");
     p.stdout.on("data",function(data){          
        stdoutCallback(output);  
     });
     p.on("exit",function(){
          completedCallback();
     });
     p.stderr.on("data",function(err){
           process.stderr.write("Error: "+err.toString("utf8"));
     });
     commandList.forEach(i=>{
         p.stdin.write(i+"\n");
     });
     p.stdin.end();
}

module.exports.bashRun = bashRun;
```

But when inside a for loop, it doesn't. It just outputs only latest element(process)'s stdout info:

```
for(var i=0;i<20;i++)
{
   var iLocal =i;
   bashRun(myList,function(myStdout){ /* only result for iLocal=19 !*/},function(){});
}
```

I need this asynchronously (and also concurrently with multiple child processes) give output from each `stdoutCallback` functions to do some processing in it. While stdout doesn't work, `completedCallback` is called 20 times at least so there must be still 20 processes throughout some time slice but not sure if they existed on same slice of time.

What am I doing wrong so that spawned child processes can not give their output to nodejs? (why only last of them (i=19) can?)

I tried to exchange spawn with `fork` but now it gives error

```
     p.stdout.on("data",function(data){
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
```

How can I use something else to retain same functionality of above module?

Comment: Looks like something to do with scope value of `i`. How are you computing the value of `myList`?

Comment: I'm using local var for that. Should I try local const?

Comment: try `for(let i=0;i<20;i++)`

Comment: Yes, thank you now it works. I think I missed some basic training about javascript. I'll accept if you make an answer.

Comment: Adding as answer for reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like issue with scope value of `i`, try changing loop to use `let`.

Eg: `for(let i=0;i<20;i++)`

Comment: Then `var` was acting like a global static variable of C++?

Comment: Yes, `var` has global scope, while `let` has block level scope. more info here - https://wesbos.com/for-of-es6/